# How to pre-populate specific text from specific referrers URLs to a search form?

Tags: html, referrer

Here´s exactly the problem: we have an HTML page with a search form, and need to take specific parts of specific referrers URLs and pre-populate them to the search form.

So that the user only have to click on search without manually entering the query (as it would be already there).

Here are 2 examples referrers URLs with parameters and directories

1) http://www.bing.com/search?q=tiny+cats&form=MOZSBR&pc=MOZI
(So if the referrer is bing.com, the text to get is from the "q" param. = "tiny+cats" in this case)

2) http://cutestcatpics.com/tag/tiny-cats/pages/1.php
(So if the referrer is cutestcatpics.com, the text to get is from the 2nd. level directory = "tiny-cats" in this case)

Here is the html page with the search form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-

transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" target="_blank" id="search-box">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any cool dev can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use JavaScript to parse the referrer url and set the input's value. Here's a starting point:

```
function getReferrerVariable(variable) {
    var referer = document.referrer;
    var query = referer.split('?')[1];
    if(typeof query === 'undefined') return '';
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}

var input = document.getElementsByName("q")[0];
var term = urldecode(getReferrerVariable('q'));
input.value = term;
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NgeHE/

Now you need to modify the code to handle your second case.